# Deleting multiple lines of HTML comment using sed

Tags: sed, replace

This is what I came up with but it doesn't work with multiple lines:

`sed -i '/<!-- my comment -->.*<!-- \/my comment end -->/d' my_file`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Since `sed` in its default mode operates on a line-by-line basis, an (admittedly obfuscated) approach would be to replace the newline characters with something else (such as the NULL character `\x00`) before feeding the the content into `sed`:

`tr '\n' '\x00' <my_file`

`sed` then sees the content as one line. However,

`sed -e 's/<!-- my comment -->.*<!-- \/my comment end -->//'`

will not work due to the greedy matching nature of `sed`. We could implement a non-greedy match by matching everything inside the comment up to the first `<` character, but this would work only if HTML comments were not allowed to contain `<` characters (and, in particular, other HTML tags), which we cannot assume.

To solve this, we'll convert the sequence `<!` to a single character not used elsewhere in the file, for which we can construct a non-greedy match. We'll choose the special character `\x01` for this purpose, which we convert back to `<!` after the non-greedy match:

`sed -e $'s/<!/\x01/g' -e $'s/\x01-- my comment -->[^\x01]*\x01-- \/my comment end -->//g'`

(note the use of the shell syntax `$''` instead of `''` to pass the literal single-byte character \x01 to `sed`)

In a third stage, the NULL characters are converted back into newlines:

`tr '\x00' '\n'`

And finally, empty lines are suppressed by another invocation of `sed`:

`sed -e '/^$/d'`

In summary,

`tr '\n' '\x00' <my_file |sed -e $'s/<!/\x01/g' -e $'s/\x01-- my comment -->[^\x01]*\x01-- \/my comment end -->//g' |tr '\x00' '\n'|sed -e '/^$/d'`

More elegant solutions exist if you choose to use different tools (`awk` or `perl` one-liners) instead of `sed`, such as:

`perl -0pe 's/<!-- my comment -->.*?<!-- \/my comment end -->//gs' my_file`

Comment: I changed my suggested answer to work around this.